# Кто Онлайн

Tags: веб-программирование

Помогите реализовать "кто онлайн" на сайт, мне нужно как вытаскивать логины пользователей, которые онлайн и просто количество гостей...

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для авторизованных пользователей записывайте в БД при каждом обновлении страницы время в unixtime, для не авторизованных аналогично но идентифицируйте по SSID к примеру, для того что бы узнать сколько человек онлайн вытаскивайте из базы список пользователей у которых время последнего визита отличается не более чем на 5 минут.
Вот собственно и все.